# Alternative Method Of Calling This Variadic Function

Tags: c, variadic

I wrote a variadic function which takes as first argument a number N and as the next N arguments it takes N variables of type `double`. Furthermore, this function returns the sum of these N variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double foo(int arg_count, ...)
{
      va_list ap;

      int i;
      double sum = 0;

      va_start(ap, arg_count);

      for (i = 0; i < arg_count; i++) {
          sum += va_arg(ap, double);
      }

      va_end(ap);

      return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, i;
    double *p, rez;

    printf("N= ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    p = (double *) calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    if (p == NULL) {
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("p[%d]= ", i);
        scanf("%lf", &p[i]);
    }

    printf("\n%lf\n", (rez = foo(n, p[0], p[1], p[2])));

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this program, for example, returns only the sum of the first 3 elements of `double *p`, regardless of the value of N (which is hold by `int n`).

If I want it to return the sum of, let's say, the first 10 elements, then I'd have to re-write the above code...

```
printf("\n%lf\n", (rez = foo(n, p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], p[7], p[8], p[9])));
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Use a linked list or an array.

Comment: Common ways to do this is also to add a magic terminator (if passing pointers, it's `NULL` (maybe try `DBL_MAX`?). See the `execv` family of functions for examples of various ways this is done

Answer (score 2):

Allow for both a variadic version and an array version.

Look up the implementation of `execl` and `execv`.

`execl` takes variadic arguments ending in NULL, while `execv` takes an array of arguments (ending in a NULL pointer).

This can be extended to your example.

```
fool(n, p[0], p[1], p[2]);
```

and

```
foov(n, p);
```

but instead of ending in NULL, you use `n` to specify the number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular function and pass the array as an argument.

```
double foo(int arg_count, double p[])
{
      int i;
      double sum = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < arg_count; i++) {
          sum += p[i];
      }

      return sum;
}


double sum1 = foo(3, p);
// Sum of the first 3 elements.

double sum2 = foo(10, p);
// Sum of the first 10 elements.
```